# Read and Add properties file from and to an APK file from code

Tags: android, apk

When you add firebase libraries or GooglePlayService libraries into your app, and then export an APK file, you'll see some properties files inside the APK zip file:

[image: APK zip file iamge]

And those file contain contents like below:

```
version=16.5.0
client=play-services-measurement
play-services-measurement_client=16.5.0
```

My question is:

How can I **Add and Read these properties file to and from APK file using code**?

Answer (score 0):

we can read it from build.gradle using below code.

```
String libVersionName = your.lib.package.name.BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME;
```

---

**UPDATED ANSWER :**

Create one task in build.gradle which you need to execute before creating build and task should have facility to create one file and you have to write all the version codes in that file.

you can refer [this link](https://guides.gradle.org/writing-gradle-tasks/) for writing task.

Comment: So if I create a text file with this format, and inject it to the APK, I can read it like this? What about custom property name?

Comment: Not sure about your answer but try to create one task in build.gradle which need to execute before creating build and task should have facility to create one file and you have to write all the codes in that file.